# Jenkins won't build specified git branch

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have set up a Jenkins job which is explicitly configured to observe to branches, "integration" and "master" and build them upon changes (checking every minute).

For some reason, the job only builds integration. Even if there are no changes in integration but in master and when I attempt to manually start the build, the job builds the most recent integration again.

I have tried some variations in naming and ordering, but without any effect. The only way to build the master is to remove the integration specification from the job, then manually build it or wait for the automatic polling of the repository.

I run Jenkins in version 1.5, but the problem appeared some version earlier.

```
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@1.1.26">
<configVersion>2</configVersion>
<userRemoteConfigs>
  <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    <name></name>
    <refspec></refspec>
    <url>git@testserver:theRepository.git</url>
  </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
</userRemoteConfigs>
<branches>
  <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    <name>master</name>
  </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
  <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    <name>integration</name>
  </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
</branches>
<disableSubmodules>false</disableSubmodules>
<recursiveSubmodules>false</recursiveSubmodules>
<doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
<authorOrCommitter>true</authorOrCommitter>
<clean>false</clean>
<wipeOutWorkspace>false</wipeOutWorkspace>
<pruneBranches>false</pruneBranches>
<remotePoll>false</remotePoll>
<ignoreNotifyCommit>false</ignoreNotifyCommit>
<useShallowClone>false</useShallowClone>
<buildChooser class="hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser"/>
<gitTool>Default</gitTool>
<submoduleCfg class="list"/>
<relativeTargetDir></relativeTargetDir>
<reference></reference>
<excludedRegions></excludedRegions>
<excludedUsers></excludedUsers>
<gitConfigName></gitConfigName>
<gitConfigEmail></gitConfigEmail>
<skipTag>false</skipTag>
<includedRegions></includedRegions>
<scmName></scmName>
```

Comment: can you post the relevant section of your job config file?

Comment: Sure. I edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your job and click on 'Configure', you should be taken to a URL like `http://[HOSTNAME]:8080/job/[JOBNAME]/configure` .  Under the 'Source Code Management' section, you have presumably selected the 'Git' radio button.  Check the 'Branches to build' subsection - this should tell you specifically what it is cloning, and you can change the branch name here if you wish.